# JSON decoding returns NULL, error: Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: php, mysql, json, encryption, encoding

To protect user data in the database (MySQL) I store sensitive (session, IP, user id, etc) data in an array, encode it into JSON, and store the JSON string encrypted in the database.

On retrieval of the data, I decrypt the data again, using a key personal to that record, and decode the JSON to an array again. Or at leas that is what I am planning to do.

The problem is that on decoding the JSON string, it fails silently and returns NULL. When getting the last JSON error it says "Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded"

So let's go through the process. (Simplified of course)
Simply encoding and decoding an array works fine, no surprise there:

```
$data = array("test" => 1, "try" => "foo");
$json = json_encode($data);
$result = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($data);
var_dump($json);
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(2) { ["test"]=> int(1) ["try"]=> string(3) "foo" } 
string(22) "{"test":1,"try":"foo"}" 
array(2) { ["test"]=> int(1) ["try"]=> string(3) "foo" }
```

When I try this with the encoding included:

```
$data = array("test" => 1, "try" => "foo");
$json = json_encode($data);
$randKey = "someStrongKey";
$encoded = encrypt($json, $randKey);
$decoded = decrypt($encoded, $randKey);
$result = json_decode($decoded, true);

var_dump($data);
var_dump($json);
var_dump($encoded);
var_dump($decoded);
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(2) { ["test"]=> int(1) ["try"]=> string(3) "foo" } 
string(22) "{"test":1,"try":"foo"}" 
string(44) "k4a8q/zICngAoxtbhpnsf23J89M5Lmc14DBjpxG098M=" 
string(32) "{"test":1,"try":"foo"}" 
NULL
```

The used encrypt and decrypt functions:

```
function encrypt($data, $key) {
   $salt = "strongsalthere";
   $key = substr(hash('sha256', $salt.$key.$salt), 0, 32);
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
   $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
   return $encrypted;
}

function decrypt($data, $key) {
   $salt = "strongsalthere";
   $key = substr(hash('sha256', $salt.$key.$salt), 0, 32);
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
   $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
   return $decrypted;
}
```

So as you can see, when I encrypt the data, and lateron decrypt it. I retrieve the exact same string. But for some reason the JSON can't be decoded and getting the last JSON error shows "Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded".

What am I missing here? I do notice that the original JSON string only has 22 characters and the decoded one has 32. What is up with that? I guess that is part of the problem.

### Solution

I can't answer my own question since it has been flagged as duplicate, but I am sure more people will run into this problem and the post that has been referred to is something that didn't turn up when I googled the problem myself, so I'll add the solution in here.

Apparently the mcrypt and decrypt function add zero padding to the data to make it an exact multiple of the block length. This zero padding is thus added to the data but is invisible (because it is binary padding) if you print out the String. (That's why the String output looked the same but had a different byte length as I mentioned earlier.)

The JSON decode function is not able to handle those zero padded bytes so it just returns null.

To resolve this issue, one must always first remove this zero padding from the string before decoding the JSON.

```
$jsonString = rtrim($jsonString, "\0");
```

So when you want to turn the decrypted data into an array using JSON.

```
$data = array("test" => 1, "try" => "foo");
$json = json_encode($data);
$randKey = "someStrongKey";
$encoded = encrypt($json, $randKey);
$decoded = decrypt($encoded, $randKey);
$decoded = rtrim($decoded, "\0");
$result = json_decode($decoded, true);
```

This will produce the expected output and creates the original array again.

Comment: I see this might be a duplicate post. The previous post you referred to has a very vague title and would definitely not have been something I'd Google since the question already is the answer to my question on itself. Which is that extra characters are added, which are invisible in most browsers except FireFox. I was not aware of that. Mentioning the existence of the padding would have been the answer by itself.

Anyway thanks, I was not aware of the padding, the simple trim function clears it right up!

Comment: zero-byte padding on the decrypted string?

Comment: I'll add the solution to the question.